# How to Fetch Data based on columns data match using SQL

Tags: sql, self-join

Looking for small help, it i need to fetch data from one Table which will have data for all years like 2009,2010,2011 etc.

I need to create a SQL query which will pull data based on whether it has matching rows for particular year

This query will help users in fetching product prices in 2011 fo products enterd in 2010

Sample data

```
ProductID      price                  year 
1020           2000 USD                2009
1030           100  USD                2009
1030           150  USD                2010
1020           300  USD                2011
1020           310  USD                2012
1030           160  USD                2012
1040           400  USD                2012
```

Below Query is what i wrote i have little doubt so please correct me

```
select * 
from productstbl a ,productstbl b
where Year = '2012' and 
      ProductID in(select b.ProductID from productstbl where b.Year = '2011') and 
      a.ProductID=b.ProductID
```

Comment: please explain in detail what is your requirement,its not clear,tabulate your expected result to have better idea

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**20 years** ago!). ***Please*** stop using it

Comment: there are two tables right? and year is common column in both ? which is the common column in both tables?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select * from productstbl 
where ( year = '2012' or year = '2011' )
and ProductID in (select ProductID from productstbl where year='2011' and year='2012' )
```

Answer (score 0):

Subquery version

```
SELECT
  ProductID,
  price as ThisYear,
  (SELECT b.price FROM productstbl b 
   WHERE b.ProductID=a.ProductID
   AND b.year=2011) as LastYear 
FROM productstbl a
WHERE year=2012
ORDER BY ProductID
```

If it's MS SQL I'd add TOP 1 in the subquery, just in case the data has more than 1 row and breaks things. Or GROUP BY ProductID and use the min() or max() price as required.

And maybe a Coalesce around the subquery to default to a sane default value if it returns nothing and ends up Null

Comment: Thank you all MrSuzzy button query gave me little help